# Responsive thumbnail carousel

Tags: jquery

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/ZrHfu/1/

Demo here - http://www.ttmt.org.uk/forum/thumb_test/

I'm trying to create a responsive thumbnail carousel - I've seen plugins to do this 
but they all need images the same size, I need something with images in different sizes.

It's very basic - list of images floated left, overflow: hidden on container.

I have left/right buttons, when the button is clicked I'm trying to move the ul with the images left/right.

Only the right button is connected.

My problem is it only works once.

If you click the right button, the images move left, click it a second time and nothing happens.

Why does it work only once.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Title of the document</title>
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="keywords" content="">
      <meta name="robots" content="">

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />

      </head>

    <body>


        <a class="arrow left">&larr;</a>

        <div class="thumbs">

          <ul>

            <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/01.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/02.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/03.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/04.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/05.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/06.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/07.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/08.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/09.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/10.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/11.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/12.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/13.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/14.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/15.jpg" /></a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>

        <a class="arrow right">&rarr;</a>


        <script src="js/hel.js"></script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click the right button, the images move left because you are applying width of the `.thumbs` class div as left to the `ul` element. And second time you are trying to apply same width which is already set as left to `ul` element. So this is why nothing happens.

**Solution:**
You need to retrieve left value of `ul` element and add it to the width of `.thumbs` class and apply value to `animate` function.

I updated code to move further.Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrHfu/2/